# How to get automatic type inference for generic static function for extension on Task

Tags: swift, async-await

I have written this extension to simplify the code when awaiting multiple async tasks in parallel.

```swift
extension Task{
    static func race<T>(_ tasks:[() async throws -> T]) async throws -> T
    {
        return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: T.self) { taskGroup in
            for task in tasks {
                taskGroup.addTask(operation: task)
            }
            let first = try await taskGroup.next()
            taskGroup.cancelAll()
            return first!
        }
    }
    
    static func all<T>(_ tasks:[() async throws -> T]) async throws -> [T]
    {
        return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: T.self) { taskGroup in
            for task in tasks {
                taskGroup.addTask(operation: task)
            }
            return try await taskGroup.collectAsArray()
        }
    }
}

extension AsyncSequence{
    func collectAsArray() async rethrows -> [Element]
    {
        var results: [Element] = []
        for try await result in self
        {
            results.append(result)
        }
        return results
    }
}
```

But I get `Generic parameter 'Failure' could not be inferred` and `Generic parameter 'Success' could not be inferred` error when using them

```swift
let x = try await Task.race([{return 1},{return 2}])
let y = try await Task.all([{return 1},{return 2}])
```

So instead I have to get rid of the error by specifying the return type explicitly

```swift
let x = try await Task<Int,Error>.race([{return 1},{return 2}])
let y = try await Task<Int,Error>.all([{return 1},{return 2}])
```

Is it possible to have it automatically infer the return type and error type so that I don't need to write them explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at how the other static methods on `Task` are declared, e.g. [`sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(nanoseconds:)). They all have constraints on the `Success` and/or `Failure` type parameters. `sleep` requires that `Success` and `Failure` are both `Never`, for example. Your static methods can do this too.

Instead of declaring an additional type parameter `T`, you can just reuse the existing `Success` type parameter. Then you can require the `Failure` type parameter to be `Never` (or any other `Error` type - it doesn't really matter which).

Also, the methods should take `@Sendable` closures to be completely safe. The caller would also have to pass in `@Sendable` closures.

```
extension Task where Failure == Never {
    static func race(_ tasks: [@Sendable () async throws -> Success]) async throws -> Success
    {
        return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Success.self) { taskGroup in
            for task in tasks {
                taskGroup.addTask(operation: task)
            }
            let first = try await taskGroup.next()
            taskGroup.cancelAll()
            return first!
        }
    }
}
```

Taking an array this way makes Swift unable to infer the `@Sendable`ness at the call site, so you'd have to specify it explicitly:

```
try await Task.race([
    { @Sendable in await doSomething() },
    { @Sendable in await doSomeOtherThing() }
])
```

I would recommend adding an overload that takes varargs:

```
static func race(_ tasks: (@Sendable () async throws -> Success)...) async throws -> Success
```

```
try await Task.race(
    { await doSomething() },
    { await doSomeOtherThing() }
)
```